# Ubuntu 16.04 ok for HP Touchsmart 15

Tags: 16.04, unity, hp, .desktop

I'm currently using HP Touchsmart 15 and i accidentally installed Ubuntu 16.04 over my windows 10.So as i;m currently posting through Ubuntu ATM, is Ubuntu compatible with my laptop? It says it's compatible for v14.04 and it works fine currently, but I'm just worry about it freaking out or something and stop working. When i try to look it up, Ubuntu 16.04 shows no working hp laptops:

https://certification.ubuntu.com/certification/make/HP/?query=&category=Laptop&release=16.04+LTS&level=Any

Is my laptop good for this version of ubuntu?

Sincerely,
Being paranoid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put down the doobie, you're fine. (jk)

Coming to you from Ubuntu 17 on an HP Envy. All is well. If you like your Windows apps, do a little research and learn to use WINE. You'll fall in love with your computer all over again.